# LeftOuterJoin in Flink (JAVA API)

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-flink, bigdata

I am trying to do a LeftOuterJoin in Flink. 
I do not try to implement the leftOuterJoin myself as it is done
with the CoGroupFunction here: https://gist.github.com/mxm/c2e9c459a9d82c18d789

I am trying to use the FlatJoinFunction:

```
    public static final class leftOuter implements FlatJoinFunction<Tuple3<String,String,String>, Tuple2<String,String>, Tuple2<String,String>>{


    @Override
    public void join(Tuple3<String, String, String> in1,
            Tuple2<String, String> in2,
            Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.collect(new Tuple2<String,String>(in1.f0, in2.f1 == null ? "null" : in2.f1));

    }

}
```

I call this function like:

```
        input1.leftOuterJoin(input2).where(0)
            .equalTo(1)
            .with(new leftOuter());
```

Unfortunately I get a NullPointerException in the out.collect line.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the left outer join.

Given your program, the left outer join calls the `JoinFunction` in two cases:

1. if both inputs, `input1` and `input2`, have records with the same join key, `join()` is called for each element of the Cartesian product of this key.
2. if the left input, `input1`, has records with a key that is not present in the right input (`input2`), `join()` is called for each record with this key of `input1` and `null` for the right input.

You should add a check for `in2 == null` to your `JoinFunction`.

Comment: Thank you! I think it worked (need to check the results).

The code looks like:
http://pastebin.com/SjB27Qyt
now.